# How to subscribe to `newBlockHeaders` on local RSK node over websockets?

Tags: websocket, web3js, rsk

I'm connecting to RSKj using the following endpoint:

```
ws://localhost:4444/
```

... However, I am unable to connect.

Note that the equivalent HTTP endpoint `http://localhost:4444/`
work for me, so I know that my RSKj node is running properly.

I need to listen for `newBlockHeaders`, so I prefer to use WebSockets (instead of HTTP).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSKj by default uses `4444` as the port for the HTTP transport;
and `4445` as the port for the Websockets transport.
Also note that the websockets endpoint is not at `/`,
but rather at `websocket`.
Therefore use `ws://localhost:4445/websocket` as your endpoint.

If you're using web3.js,
you can create a `web3` instance that connects over Websockets
using the following:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');
const wsEndpoint = 'ws://localhost:4445/websocket';
const wsProvider =
  new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(wsEndpoint);
const web3 = new Web3(wsProvider);
```

The second part of your question can be done
using `eth_subscribe` on `newBlockHeaders`.
Using the `web3` instance from above like so:

```js
// eth_subscribe newBlockHeaders
web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function(error, blockHeader) {
  if (!error) {
    // TODO something with blockHeader
  } else {
    // TODO something with error
  }
});
```